# Vim 'n' not working in command mode

Tags: bash, vim

I have the line:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

with my cursor at the start. When I hit `fc` it correctly finds the first `c` at the end of `public`. When I press `n`, I expect it to jump to the second; instead I get the error `E486: Pattern not found: alias rc`

`rc` was an alias in my ~.bashrc that expaned to `vim ~/.bashrc` 
After experiencing this problem I removed the line (though I can't see why that should be the cause) and restarted bash and vim. But the problem still persists. I checked my vimrc and there is no mention of either alias or rc or any mapping for `n`.

In any case, here is the vimrc: http://codepaste.net/yz3b1r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `f` command finds a single character. `fc` finds the next `c`.

To repeat an `f` search, type `;` (or `,` to repeat the search in the opposite direction).

The `/` command finds a regular expression.

To repeat a `/` search, type `n` (or `N` to repeat the search in the opposite direction).

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you have search for "rc" in another vim session.

   If you search for test (`/test`), and open another file without "test" using vim, you will properly get the following error when you try to search for "test":

   `eE486: Pattern not found: test`
2. The fastest way I can think about to go to the second `c` is `2fc` if you don't want to do searching.